# Text align changes in grid view

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, gridview

The following gird view has a record which has three cells. These cells are date, name, and view. When name is long name (more than 200 charters), the record height changes and that effects the date alignment. How to keep date alignment in the upper side of its cell?

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" Width="100%" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoGenerateColumns="False" GridLines="None" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333">
    <alternatingrowstyle backcolor="White" />
        <columns>
            <asp:boundfield datafield="eventDate" sortexpression="eventDate" itemstyle-width="30px" controlstyle-font-underline="true" dataformatstring="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}">
                <controlstyle font-underline="True"></controlstyle>
                    <itemstyle width="30px"></itemstyle>
            </asp:boundfield>
            <asp:boundfield datafield="eventName" sortexpression="eventName" controlstyle-font-underline="true">
                <controlstyle font-underline="True"></controlstyle>
            </asp:boundfield>
            <asp:templatefield itemstyle-horizontalalign="Center">
                <itemtemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkView" runat="server" Text="More" OnClick="View2" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Id") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
                </itemtemplate>
                <itemstyle horizontalalign="Center"></itemstyle>
            </asp:templatefield>
        </columns>
    <editrowstyle backcolor="#2461BF" />
    <footerstyle backcolor="#507CD1" font-bold="True" forecolor="White" />
    <pagerstyle backcolor="#2461BF" forecolor="White" horizontalalign="Center" />
    <rowstyle backcolor="#EFF3FB" font-underline="False" forecolor="#FF3300" />
    <selectedrowstyle backcolor="#D1DDF1" font-bold="True" forecolor="#333333" />
    <sortedascendingcellstyle backcolor="#F5F7FB" />
</asp:GridView>
```